# Combine 3 queries to one in Informix SQL

Tags: sql, informix, cucm

I have 3 sql queries that I would like to combine in one.

I know the value 'UKLN_8945_UDP' that I use in 1st query, that 1st query gives me two values that I can't read so I need to run 2 other queries to return values that I can read.

The 1st query is

```
run sql SELECT EMD.fkdevice,EMD.fkEnduser FROM extensionmobilitydynamic EMD WHERE EMD.fkdevice_currentloginprofile = (SELECT d1.pkid FROM device d1 WHERE d1.name = 'UKLN_8945_UDP')
```

That query returns 2 values:
    fkdevice: f3b95ea0-63f8-49d1-911f-cacdd68d0967
    fkenduser: 5a71fc04-d348-8115-9ff9-ea78f38b06fc

The 2nd query is using the fkdevice from the 1st query

```
run sql select D.name SEPDname from device D where D.pkid = 'f3b95ea0-63f8-49d1-911f-cacdd68d0967'
```

That query returns 1 value:
    sepdname: SEP0057D2C01D0B

The 3rd query is using the fkenduser from the 1st query

```
run sql select E.userid from enduser E where E.pkid = '5a71fc04-d348-8115-9ff9-ea78f38b06fc'
```

That query returns 1 value: 
    userid: UKLN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   EMD.fkdevice
,        EMD.fkEnduser
,        D2.name
,        E.userid
FROM     device D1
JOIN     extensionmobilitydynamic EMD 
ON       EMD.fkdevice_currentloginprofile = D1.pkid
JOIN     device D2
ON       D2.pkid = EMD.fkdevice
JOIN     enduser E
ON       E.pkid = EMD.fkEnduser
WHERE    D1.name = 'UKLN_8945_UDP'
```